# Can non-table elements be placed between table "root" elements?

Tags: html

According to [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), The following HTML is valid:

```
<table id="searchForm" class="formLabelsLeft" >
  <caption>Search criteria</caption>
  <tbody>...</tbody>
</table>
```

But I'm wondering, is `<caption>` allowed between *table* tag and *tbody* tag?
If yes, why? And can other elements be placed here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`<caption>` represents a table caption](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-caption-element), so of course it would be allowed in a `<table>` element.

The only elements that are allows as children of a `<table>` are `<caption>`, `<colgroup>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>`. In HTML5, `<tr>` elements are also allowed if there are no table header, body or footer elements — those `<tr>` elements will be placed into their own `<tbody>` in the DOM.

`<caption>` is actually *only* allowed as the first child of a `<table>`. You cannot place one after any of the other elements listed if they are present, or outside of a table altogether.

Comment: That was the one element I did not know was a part of the table elements. Thanks :)